# App rejected due to "iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution"

Tags: ios, ipad

My app got rejected by the apple because of the reason "**iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution**".Apple suggested that "**to support the iPad 3GS 2X, and this issue is usually resolved through settings in "compatibility" mode. "no black bar's or borders"**".So,my question is how to set and run the app in compatibility mode.Any one having this issue please help on this issue.I have no idea to go forward. Please any suggestions and help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you've not made this app also for 3,5-inch devices. Does your app support them?

Comment: No ,my app developed only for iPhone 4inch screen only.

Comment: Which iPhones? 4 inch and 3.5 inch?

Comment: we developed on iPhone - 4 inch only

Comment: Yeah, there's the problem. You also have to develop for 3.5-Inch devices. In you can't See some things Prozent you can't use it in 3.5-Inch, it'll be rejected.

Comment: Any other solutions you know please let me know

Answer (score 0):

The above error says that you have not added the required images, splash, launch images for the retina resolution devices. You have to add launch , Splash images and logos for all possible type of apple devices. Please check below link :

[Required image.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1)

Comment: I checked all images whatever i used in the app ,both images were added(retina and non-retina).